# Is there a convenient way on Mac to package a .py file to be an executable file for Windows system?

Tags: python, exec, exe, pyinstaller

I'm using PyCharm on Mac to code and now I want to package a .py file to be an exe. file for Windows 10, but after using PyInstaller(-F -w) to package the file, it produced an .exec file an it can't be opened on Windows, so is there anything I can do to solve it?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

i am also using mac but i had 50 gb of partition, in which i simply installed windows via bootloader. its nice and easy way out. you will find nice community using windows, rather than mac. i hadnot paid for windows.